# How to set profile picture obtained from facebook login to user profile in another activity

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, facebook-login

I am using facebook login in my application. I am using `Profile` class to get the basic user info like Name, Profile Picture. Here is the code snippet of method `updateUI()` which I am using to update the UI in my login activity.

```
private void updateUI() {
        boolean enableButtons = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null;
          Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        if (enableButtons && profile != null) {
            profilePictureView.setProfileId(profile.getId());
            Toast.makeText(login.this,"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            greeting.setText(profile.getName());
            url.setText(profile.getProfilePictureUri(60,60).toString());
        }
        else {
            profilePictureView.setProfileId(null);
            greeting.setText(null);
            url.setText(null);
        }
    }
```

Now I want to pass the profile picture to another activity and set it there as a rounded thumbnail. I want to know how to do that. Here is the code of Profile section in another activity where I want to set the image. Currently I have put up a `drawable` resource there.

```
drawer.addProfile(
                new DrawerProfile()
                        .setId(1)
                        .setRoundedAvatar((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.appeti))
                        .setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ghewar))
                        .setName(getString(R.string.welcome))
                        .setDescription(name)
                        .setOnProfileClickListener(new DrawerProfile.OnProfileClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DrawerProfile drawerProfile, long id) {
                                Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Clicked profile #" + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),login.class);
                                startActivity(login);
}
})
);
```

I am using [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/HeinrichReimer/material-drawer) library of github to show profile in Navigation Drawer in other activity. One way I can think is the URL of profile picture which I can get from `url` text field as shown in the method `updateUI()` and pass through `intent` to another activity. But I don't know how to use this URL to set a thumbnail in the drawer profile. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple solution I can think of is that you can use libraries like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) to fetch the image from a url and load it directly to the imageview

The code will be using the Picasso library

```
Picasso.with(context).load("Facebook_profile_picture_URL").into(imageView);
```

Just one line of code

Regarding the Volley library it requires some setup first.

Comment: I don't want to set image in a `ImageView` I am using a line in code `setRoundedAvatar((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.appeti))` I also want to know what to write to replace the argument in it. The method needs a argument of type `android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable`.